# How to verify AddSingleton with special type is received using NSubstitute framework

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, xunit.net, nsubstitute

I want to mock `IServiceCollection` to check if `AddSingleton` is called with a specific Interface and concrete type using `Nsubstite` mocking library and `xUnit`.

This is my unit test:

```
[Fact] 
public checkIfServicesAddedTo_DI()
{
    var iServiceCollectionMock = Substitute.For<IServiceCollection>();
    var iConfiguration = Substitute.For<IConfiguration>();
    MatchServicesManager servicesManager = new MatchServicesManager();
    servicesManager.AddServices(iServiceCollectionMock, iConfiguration);

    iServiceCollectionMock.Received(1).AddSingleton(typeof(IMatchManager) , typeof(MatchManager));
}
```

this is the implementation:

```
public class MatchServicesManager : IServicesManager
{
    public void AddServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IMatchManager, MatchManager>();
    }
}
```

I expect the test to succeed, but it fails with the following error:

> NSubstitute.Exceptions.ReceivedCallsException : Expected to receive
> exactly 1 call matching: Add(ServiceDescriptor) Actually received no
> matching calls. Received 1 non - matching call(non - matching
> arguments indicated with '*' characters): Add(*ServiceDescriptor *)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AddSingleton` is an extension method on `IServiceCollection`. This makes it a little more difficult to mock or verify.

Consider using an actual implementation of the interface and then verify expected behavior after exercising the method under test.

For example

```
public void checkIfServicesAddedTo_DI() {
    //Arrange
    var services = new ServiceCollection();// Substitute.For<IServiceCollection>();
    var configuration = Substitute.For<IConfiguration>();
    MatchServicesManager servicesManager = new MatchServicesManager();

    //Act
    servicesManager.AddServices(services, configuration);

    //Assert (using FluentAssertions)
    services.Count.Should().Be(1);
    services[0].ServiceType.Should().Be(typeof(IMatchManager));
    services[0].ImplementationType.Should().Be(typeof(MatchManager));
}
```